# Different handling of division by zero

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

MMA differently handles division by zero. How to control this behavior?

In this case it delivers the expected error:

`i/(i + k) /. {i -> 0, k -> 0}`

`(* Indeterminate *)`

but if you calculate the same using `Sum`

`Sum[i/(i + k), {i, 0, 0}] /. k -> 0` or `Sum[0/k, {i, 0, 0}] /. k -> 0`

`(* 0 *)`

the result is 0 presumably because MMA internally uses the limit:

`Limit[0/(0 + k), k -> 0]`

`(* 0 *)`

Comment: If you `Trace` the evaluation you will see that the `Sum` is evaluated symbolically prior to the replacement. The symbolic `Sum` is zero and there is no `k` to be replaced. Also, `Inactive[Sum][i/(i + k), {i, 0, 0}] /. k -> 0 // Activate` evaluates to `1` since Mathematica always immediately simplifies `symbol/symbol` to `1`

Comment: but why does it not reduce to ```symbol/symbol``` in the first case? How can the symbol reduction in the sum be switched off?

Comment: Use `Trace` and you will see that both variables are first replaced by zero resulting in `0/(0+0)` so there is no `symbol/symbol`

Comment: If you want a non-standard interpretation specify the conditions and results with `Piecewise` or equivalent structure.

Comment: Expressions are evaluated in a certain order. `Sum[]` is evaluated in your code before the replacement `k -> 0` (which is in no way connected with limits). The sum becomes `0`, because `0/k` evaluates to `0` when `i = 0`.  Then all instances of `k` that are left (which is none) are replaced by `0`.  `Block[{k = 0}, Sum[i/(i + k), {i, 0, 0}]]` in effect has `k` and `i` evaluated simultaneously each time a term is computed. `Sum[Evaluate[i/(i + k) /. k -> 0], {i, 0, 0}]` has `k` evaluated first, before the sum is computed. `Trace[]` will show these steps.

Comment: I expect that the `Sum` becomes `0` because `0*a` is `0` for any symbolic `a`. the `Indeterminate` value comes from `Power` being evaluated first, as `a/b` is actually `a * Power[b, -1]`, and it is `Power[0, -1]` that gives `Indeterminate`. We can see that if we inactivate `Power` (thus "evaluating `*` first") we get 0: `Inactivate[0/0, Power]` yields `0`.

Comment: In the case ```Sum[0/k, {i, 0, 0}] /. k -> 0``` there is no ```i``` in the sum and one can set the upper and lower index to arbitrary but equal values, e.g. ```Sum[0/k, {i, 1, 1}] /. k -> 0``` and the result is nethertheless ```0```, the same for ```Sum[0/k, i] /. k -> 0```